# Should I connect stepper motor case to mains earth or power supply V-

Tags: stepper-motor, earth, cases

I have a stepper motor driver, the sockets have the expected V+,V-, etc. However there is a bolt with a grounding symbol on the outside, I think this connects to mains earth? The third pin on a plug? Googling seems to put forward it should be connected to the V- of the power supply.

All the sockets have +,- for inputs and such so I don't think it's for reference but to drain away any electrical noise?

The driver is [kelings](http://www.automationtechnologiesinc.com/products-page/digital-stepper-motor-driver/digital-stepper-driver-kl-4042d-heat-sink-is-included).

Comment: I think you're misrepresenting the term _grounding_. You ground stuff primarily for safety reasons, noise immunity comes second.

Comment: A photo would be helpful.

Comment: @user3169 There is a photo on the link, thankyou for your time